# How to change aos-delay value in v-for component

Tags: html, vue.js, aos.js

I render 4 div cards using v-for and I want to make it appearing one by one with the `data-aos-delay` value but no idea how to dynamically change the `data-aos-delay` value when using with `v-for`

```
<div
  v-for=" (el, I) in list"
  :key="I"
  data-aos="fade-right"
  :data-aos-delay="?"
>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add the `i` to some time, and this will increment the delay for each one

```
<div
  v-for="(el, i) in list"
  :key="i"
  data-aos="fade-right"
  :data-aos-delay="1000 + i * 10"
>
```

Comment: I thought this should work too, but mine doesn't seem to be honoring the delay time... `<div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 py-8 px-1 shadow-2xl aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-anchor="[data-aos-id-stats]" data-eos-delay="1000"><div class="font-red-hat-display text-3xl font-black tracking-tighter mb-1">1500+</div><div class="text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Units</div></div>` Any thoughts?